# Typeerror: Tuple Indices when iterating over cells

Tags: python, openpyxl

Quick run down; I'm trying to iterate over all cells in column "A" and output the value of the color used in the cell. This works fine when iterating over the first cell, but when it tries again I get the following error;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Luke\Desktop\test.py", line 24, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1])
  File "C:\Users\Luke\Desktop\test.py", line 11, in main
    color_dict[cell] = styles.colors.COLOR_INDEX[cell.fill.start_color.index]
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I'm lost and unsure on why this keeps occurring, any pointers on this one?

Code:

```
import sys
from openpyxl import load_workbook, styles

def main(fileName):
    color_dict = {}
    workbook = load_workbook(fileName)
    ltm = workbook.get_sheet_names()[7]
    ws = workbook.get_sheet_by_name(ltm)
    for row in ws.iter_rows("A{}:A{}".format(ws.min_row,ws.max_row)):
        for cell in row:
            color_dict[cell] = styles.colors.COLOR_INDEX[cell.fill.start_color.index]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print("Bad Syntax")
    main(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: Apparently your indexing variable is becoming a string at some point. Debug the code to find out where. Put a breakpoint (or `print`) before the `color_dict` line and inspect the variables.

Comment: in addition to @Carcigenicate you can use a print(type(cell)) to give you the type. If you're getting something like "1" then you could cast it: int(cell)

Comment: Most likely, start_color.index is a hex value which represents a color.

Comment: What if the cells don't use indexed colours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a type error because `cell.fill.start_color.index` is a string while `styles.colors.COLOR_INDEX()` accepts an integer as a parameter. Check the type and contents of  `cell.fill.start_color.index` and explicitly convert it into int.